# AVPlayerViewController not rotating

Tags: swift, xcode, autorotate, avplayerviewcontroller

My custom AVPlayerViewController won't autorotate if the previous view controller has been instantiated. If I present the AVPlayerViewController, it rotates, and if I present the previous view controller, it rotates. Here's my code for instantiating a view controller :

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieVC") as! MovieVC
vc.movie = self.movie
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

In this situation I am creating a copy of the current view controller with different information. If there is no way to fix the autorotating error, is there a different way to present the same view controller?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are *not* presenting the view controller. You are pushing it. That means that the navigation controller itself is in charge of rotation, so you don't get any special autorotation for this view controller.

The *only* way to give this view controller its own power over autorotation *is* to present it:

```
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. The AVPlayerViewController still didn't rotate.

Comment: Well, I don't have any knowledge of what your AVPlayerViewController autorotation settings are. But I assure you that if it is set to rotate, it will.

Comment: I found that if the AVPlayerViewController is presented in landscape mode and then the device's orientation changes to portrait, it autorotates, but not the other way around